# How to print all output at networkx.adjacency_matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, graph, networkx

I'm trying to convert my undirected graph into an adjacency matrix, I've used pandas and networkx. However, when printing large datasets, it doesn't print it all. How can I fix this?

Code:

```
import pandas
import networkx
data = pandas.read_excel("Book1.xlsx", header=None)
edgeList = data.values.tolist()
G = networkx.Graph()
for i in range(len(edgeList)):
    G.add_edge(edgeList[i][0], edgeList[i][1], weight=edgeList[i][2])
A = networkx.adjacency_matrix(G).A
print(A)
```

Output:

```
[[0.      0.11712 0.      ... 0.      0.      0.     ]
 [0.11712 0.      0.      ... 0.      0.      0.     ]
 [0.      0.      0.      ... 0.      0.      0.     ]
 ...
 [0.      0.      0.      ... 0.      0.      0.     ]
 [0.      0.      0.      ... 0.      0.      0.     ]
 [0.      0.      0.      ... 0.      0.      0.     ]]
```

What I wanted is to see all the output because I will use it on my Prim's Algorithm. I hope you can help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import numpy as np

with np.printoptions(threshold=np.inf):
    print(A)
```

Or you can convert the array into a list and then print it:

```
print(A.tolist())
```

Comment: but the commas been removed? using the numpy. How can I add the commas?

Comment: Nevermind, I'll just use the list since it's still working for the adjacency matrix.